# How to test Custom Views in Appium in Android

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, android-uiautomator

I am testing a custom view in Android from Appium. It contains textviews, images etc but when I use UiAutomatorviewer It is taking whole as a single view.How will I test the textviews present inside the View using Appium.

Comment: if possible please attach the custom view screenshot using `UIAutomator` or `Appium Inspector`.

Comment: I too have same problem, Please update if you found any solution for this issue.

Comment: Me too , cant locate the elements within.

Comment: Any solution you guys found ?